# Is it haram to have a crush on someone?

Tags: halal-haram, relationships

Is it haram to have a crush on someone?

I have a crush on this girl (who is also Muslim) but I haven't yet spoken to her properly.  I haven't made much effort to get in touch with her or have any sort of relationship with her. We used to go to the same coaching class and our schools were separated into boys and girls. I did not intentionally gaze at her, it was unavoidable and purely unintentional as we were in the same coaching class. She just knows that I exist and nothing else has happened between us. I just wanted to know whether the feeling I'm having towards this girl is haram or halal?

Secondly is it permissible for us to make a wish to Allah swt to get us married to the person that we love?

Comment: This question is per se strange how could something we are not able to steer something -God given- which is part of our creation be haram by itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Feeling love and affection towards others (that includes to opposite genders) is a natural phenomenon. Your question really sounds same as "Is eating halal?". It is OK to love others as long as that feeling is not causing deviations in performing your daily duties and obligations and within the limits of basic Islamic principles(e.g., feeling sexually attracted towards mahrams is beyond those limits).

And yes, it is OK to make dua and ask Allah to make you get married with the person you like.

Answer (score 1):

No brother. It's not Haraam to love a girl and have feelings in your heart about her. You can also Dua to Allah Taala About getting married to your love. But remember on thing. Relationship is Haram so do not approach her for Friendship. If you really love her and want to marry her then you should meet her and tell her about it. Tell her that you are in love with her. InshAllah her feelings for you will be tge same. But don't do any kind of Relationship with her. Just stay in touch with her until you are grown up and well stable. Then you can tell your Parents about it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so that any form of pre marital relationship is allowed in Islam 
If you like the girl then you can ask dua from Allah and convince your parents to their parents for marriage.

Comment: Thank you brother, what I also want to know whether my feelings for her are also haram ? We're not in a relationship, I think it's a one sided crush

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not haram to like someone but acting upon that crush by asking them out or even just checking them out is haram.

Answer (score 0):

You can not stop yourself from having that feeling. however,acting upon that feeling or having dirty thoughts about this person is haram.

In Sha Allah you will be married to the right person

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is haram. i have the same situation and I just wish for her best in this world and the next. But I dont think of adultrey or zina for her. So, I don;t find anything wrong about it.

Answer (score 0):

Crush is not something you have control over, so it's okay. And I believe if you have the right intentions, it's completely fine to make such dua.

I have a question brother, are you from Bangladesh by any chance cause I feel like I know you. If you are, what's your name?

Answer (score -1):

Having a crush is a natural feeling you get as you get older. So it's ok as long as you don't act upon it you're fine

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Please check out a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) of our site to learn how this site works, and please cite sources and thoroughly answer the question asked.

Answer (score -1):

It's not haram at all as long as there is no sexual intercourse involved

Comment: It would improve this answer to [edit] in references from scholars who make this claim.

Answer (score -1):

It’s a natural feeling but don’t intentionally overthink about that person as that is completely forbidden in Islam